# Using Instruments to measure CPU usage: why 100%+ usage?

Tags: cpu-usage, instruments

We use Instruments Activity Monitor to measure CPU usage of our app. We see some CPU usage more than 100%. Does that mean Instruments didn't take into account multi-core of CPU? Or may be bugs of Instruments?!

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what you have tried...

Comment: Check out https://www.quora.com/What-does-100-CPU-utilization-mean for Linux. I've observed both normalized to 100% and >100% for both Linux and Windows. I can't imagine iOS is much different. I prefer the >%100 versions.